# Life of a device token received from APNS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When we register a device with APNS for push notification we receive a device token back. Is there any expiry associated with this token on APNS? Is there any timeline after which APNS will discard that token?

Answer (score 3):

The tokens do change from time to time, which is why APNS has a feedback server to alert you about tokens that don't work so you can remove them from your database. Also, APNS doesn't record the device tokens, it is up to you to upload them to a database on your server.

Comment: If APNS do not record the device token then how did our Server send the payload meant for specific devices? i.e. How does APNS makeout that it needs to send the Push Notification to this device ID. How does it work internally?

Comment: I think that you just send the push notifications to the certain device tokens, give APNS the payload, and then it sees the tokens, and basically throws the information in that direction. It has no idea where the device is, but it can still send the message.